# Why can't you lose a chess game in which you can make $2$ legal moves at once?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory, chessboard, infinite-games

So here is the Problem :-

Consider a normal chess game in an $8*8$ chessboard such that every player makes $2$ legal moves at once alternatively . Now imagine that you was asked to play with Magnus Carlsen .Then Prove that it's impossible for Magnus Carlsen to make you lose, or atleast can make you draw.

I was actually stumped when I first saw this . Also I tried thinking many normal chessgames and tried to understand what type of answer this question can take . From here I can say that a check on the $1st$ move made by any player is actually a checkmate . Other than that I have no idea, can anyone help ?

**Edit** :- I forgot to add another thing . It's given that I will be white and Magnus Carlsen will be black .

Comment: The rules are slightly unclear: I assume you are not allowed to enter check (or ignore to get out of check) in your first move even if you cure this with the second move? Or what about double-check: Can you evade these in two steps? Perhaps not, because both moves had to be legal. Then again, why would check on first move be a checkmate when beating th eking is not a valid move?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes u can think like that ,you can assume that it's a rule which is not allowed in these chess games . For now, you can assume that a check in the 1st move is a checkmate in the 2nd move.

Comment: You would be able to pull off one of those quick mates (i.e the King's pawn opening mate aka the Scholar's mate)

Comment: That is assuming you are playing white and get to move first.

Comment: True @user10354138 , it was given in the question , let me add it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While some of the details of the rules may still be ambiguous in boundary situations, it is clear that white can avoid a loss by opening with

1. ♘b1-c3,♘c3-b1

or

1. ♘g1-f3,♘f3-g1

More precisely, if either of these no-ops in fact leads to a position where black can force a win, then white could force a win by playing by black's  strategy mirrored.

Comment: Aha I got your point !! I will first assume Magnus Carlsen (black) has a winning strategy . Then on playing any those moves , I can actually take the black side and the winning strategy would have been mine !! . Magnus Carlsen can do the same as well . Hence it will always be a win or a draw for mine !

Comment: @SouradipDas Indeed the only difference is that a draw by 50-move-rule (would that be 25-move-rule?) or repeated position may be claimed earlier

Comment: I don't get this. Then in normal chess black can play by mirrored strategy and thus never lose?

Comment: @Aqua , in normal chess you can give $1$ move alternatively . In this case, we can give $2$ moves, hence moving $1$ one of the knights up and down actually keeps the position the same , in that way we can take the winning strategy from black (first we assumed black has a strategy to win) .

Comment: This is the same as Hagen wrote. I don't understand why. And black has now 2 moves of advantage, so in one moment he can give what mate and I can not mirroret that

Answer (score 2):

With the new condition that I will start as white pieces and my opponent (Magnus Carlsen in this case) as black pieces, Scholar's Mate can guarantee a win in 4 moves.

The Scholar's Mate is a 4 move mate meaning black has to play pawn e6 or pawn d5, which is a move only delaying the inevitable mate.

Comment: I actually didn't get you , how can Scholar's mate guarantee a win for mine?

Comment: @SouradipDas If you start pawn to e1 and bishop to c4, the only viable defense for black is pawn to e6 or pawn to d5. If black decides pawn to e6, you queen to h1 pinning the pawn to the king, and you put pawn to b3 so that you use your bishop to line up for mate. And in this position, whatever black does, the game is over as if black moves pawn to d5, you check with the bishop checkmate because you have two turns. If the opponent doesn't do that move, whatever black does, Queen takes pawn f7 is checkmate with two turns.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the idea of @Hagen Von Eitzen in my answer :-

First assume that Magnus Carlsen (Black Side) has a winning strategy . Then if I play either :-

$$Nc3-Nb1$$ or $$Nf3-Ng1$$ as my $2$ legal moves , I can actually get the same winning strategy from Magnus Carlsen , hence that forces me not to lose . This is like a strategy stealing from my opponent .

Answer (score 0):

There is a mathematical proof for this

Assume that there is no such strategy by which player 1 (white) would not lose. This would imply that black has a non losing strategy.

now let white move it's knight first, and take the knight back; essentially making black white (or the person who moves first )
now that would mean that black will also have no non-losing strategy

but this contradicts our assumption that black has a non losing strategy.
So by contradiction we can prove that white has a non-losing strategy and can never lose.

Comment: Your answer is nothing different than the one posted by @HagenvonEitzen.